# How to run a specific test case from a test suite using InternIO

Tags: testing, automated-tests, functional-testing, intern

Currently, I have a few test suites. To avoid running an entire test suite - how can I run just a single test case from a suite. My current workaround is to comment out test cases I don't want.

My intern.js file:

```
define({
 environments: [
    { browserName: 'chrome'},
  ],


  useSauceConnect: false,

  //functionalSuites: ['tests/projects/projectA/main.js'],

  tunnel: 'NullTunnel',

  excludeInstrumentation: /./
});
```

The following is my main.js file:

```
    define([
        'intern',
        'intern!object',
        'intern/chai!assert'        
    ],
    function (intern, registerSuite, assert) {



    registerSuite(function () {

        var someLib;


        return {
            setup: function () {

            },

            'TC001 - Functionality 1': function () {

            },

            'TC002 -  Functionality 2': function() {


            },

            'TC003 - Functionality 3': function() {


            },


        };
    });
});
```

I am running this by using the command-line: To run - I issue the following command:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/intern-runner config=tests/intern     functionalSuites=tests/projects/projectA/main.js
```

Is there a way to run say only "TC001 - Functionality 1" and other selected test cases without commenting out the other tests cases from the suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [grep command line option](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-grep). The `grep` option specifies a regular expression that filters on test ID (test IDs that match are run), giving you a lot of flexibility when specifying which tests will run. At it's simplest, you can just provide a short string, and Intern will run any tests with IDs containing that string:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/intern-runner config=tests/intern  functionalSuites=tests/projects/projectA/main grep=TC001
```